# Trying to run my index.js file but it's not working

Tags: node.js, google-chrome-devtools

Losing my mind trying to figure out the correct file path. At least I think its an error with the file path. Getting the following error in Chrome. [image: error1][image: error2]

Also added my code for index.js and app.js below. I don't understand why my app.js mongodb is functioning fine?

```
---------app.js----------
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const ejs = require("ejs");
const app = express();

const mongoose = require("mongoose");




app.use(express.static("public"));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/userDB", {useNewUrlParser:true, useUnifiedTopology: true});

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new Schema({
  username: String,
  email: String,
  password: String
});

const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

app.get("/", function(req, res){
  res.render("login");
});

app.get("/register", function(req, res){
  res.render("register");
});

app.post("/register", function(req, res){
  const newUser = new User({
    username: req.body.username,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password
  });

  newUser.save(function(err){
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
    } else{
      res.render("dashboard", {loggedInUser: req.body.username});
    }
  });

});

app.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log("server is running on port 3000");
});
```

---index.js----

alert("test");

Comment: It's not enough information to see where error is coming from. add index.js and app.js here to see.

Answer (score 0):

your two `src=""` tags are pointing to wrong place.
`app.js` is one directory up and
`/ChatApp` means it points to `/` directory.

Br,
Dulguun

Comment: maybe a noob question but what should the correct path be to both files. I tried so many variations. Also it's funny how the app.js is functioning fine but still getting the error. I'm so confused lol

Comment: are the index.js and app.js back-end code? You can't include back-end on front-end side(since it doesn't make any sense)

Comment: Seem to have fixed the issue by moving index.js to the public folder. Still not sure why I'm getting error for app.js, I must be doing something wrong. Yeah app.js is backend for my db setup and index.js I'm using for manipulating styles and DOM objects on my front end.

Comment: why do you want to include back-end code to front end? Because you can't do that. Since Back-end code runs on web-server and front end code runs on user's browser. Therefore you don't want (not allowed) to include back-end code to front end